# Selenium Python 3.4.3 Automatic Torrenting: Link section

Tags: python, selenium, bittorrent, utorrent

What i am trying to do is make a simple program that lets me run and it basically goes to Torrentz and follows a few link to finally be able to download the file through uttorent. Below is what i have coded so far and i cant seem to make the variable `linkElem` work. And i also cant seem to make `linkElem.find_elements_by_xpath` go to the link necessary. If you think you know what is wrong, please do help. 
Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://torrentz.eu/')

searchElem = browser.find_element_by_id('thesearchbox')
searchElem.send_keys('Limitless')
searchButton = browser.find_element_by_id('thesearchbutton')
searchButton.click()

linkElem = linkElem.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='results']//a[@href='/9ea0c575520a3065d85b285c9474231192368db7']")


#wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 6)
#linkElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.href, "/9ea0c575520a3065d85b285c9474231192368db7")))
#linkElem.clear()

#linkElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('S01E20 HDTV x264 LOL ettv')
#linkElem.click()


#SignIn = browser.find_elements_by_id('signIn')
#SignIn.click()
#passwordElem.submit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can and should rely on the `href` attribute value. Instead, get the links from under the `dl` elements inside the search results container. Also, add a wait:

```
# wait for search results to appear
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 6)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results dl")))

links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.results dl dt a")
links[0].click()
```

`links` in your case would contain all of the search results links, `links[0]` is the first link.

Comment: Hey @alecxe, can you please help me understand what `dl` specifically does in this case and what the variable `links` parameters does?

Comment: @stuum1. `dl` is an element name. `links` is a list of webelements. `links[0]` gives you the first element in the list.